# How to remove default partition expiration for existing table?

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery, firebase-analytics

I did steps from this guide https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/sandbox#upgrading_from_the_sandbox

But I can't find out how to remove default partition expiration for existing table and update it to "never". In API there is an opportunity only to change "defaultTableExpirationMs" to some numeric value, not to remove.

Answer (score 0):

With SQL you could do on each table:

```
ALTER TABLE mydataset.mytable
SET OPTIONS (
  expiration_timestamp=NULL
)
```

If you want to do this in batch, you could consider:

1. query [INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_OPTIONS](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-tables#table_options_view) to list all the table with an expiration timestamp
2. using [scripting](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/scripting#bigquery_scripting) to ALTER each table in a loop.